# Trigger delegate click with links

Tags: jquery, delegates, preventdefault

I have my html (this is just an example)

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="link" href="http://www.google.se">Google</li>
    <li><a class="link" href="http://www.yahoo.se">Yahoo</li>
<ul>
```

And my js

```
<script>
$('ul.menu').on('click', 'a.link', function(e, data) {
    if (data && data.run === true) {
        alert('run');
        return true;
    }
    alert('preventDefault');
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('trigger click');   
    $(this).trigger('click', {"run": true});
});
</script>
```

What I wanna do is when a user clicks on a link in the menu. Do alot of stuff (also ajax stuff).. then when everything is ready i trigger a click and it should go the the url (run the default). But it doesn't works. Why is that? Any one fixed this problem.

Update: I change the code a bit, still dont work, it alerts "run" but doesnt update the url.
http://jsfiddle.net/GgTUa/

Comment: Have you tried this? $('ul.menu a.link').on('click', function bla bla bla and alert for example alert($(this).prop("href"));

Comment: why you simply don't use location.href?

Comment: @Pavlo: Because i wan't it to be delegate, so if I add a new menu item it should still work.

Comment: @Nicolai: Because it's not a good idea. Its not equal. Could be other events on it, could be target="_blank" etc. Alot of reasons.